# loop inside another loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have this code:

```
//Value of userCount is 25
auxCount = 0;
for (int y_axis=0; y_axis<=8; y_axis++)  //ROWS
    {
        for (int x_axis=0; x_axis<=2; x_axis++) //COLUMNS
        {
            if (auxCount<userCount) {     
                NSLog(@"auxCount: %i\n",auxCount);
                NSLog(@"userCount: %i\n\n",userCount);
                UIButton *btn=       [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16+100*x_axis,115.0*y_axis,88.0 ,88.0)];
                UILabel *userLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16+100*x_axis,90+115.0*y_axis, 88.0, 15.0)];
                userLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
                userLabel.text = mensaje;

                btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
                [scrollViewUsers addSubview:btn];
                [scrollViewUsers addSubview:userLabel];

                auxCount++;

            }
        }
    }
```

With this I want a matrix with 3 columns and X rows, but only displays 3 rows and the third row only displays 1 button. And in Debug area appears:
 auxCount: 0
 userCount: 25

auxCount: 4
 userCount: 25

auxCount: 8
 userCount: 25

auxCount: 12
 userCount: 25

auxCount: 16
 userCount: 25

auxCount: 20
 userCount: 25

auxCount: 24
 userCount: 25

auxCount increments by 4 by 4. I think that is because the if instructions are executed only by the first for loop but I don't know why.
Please, I need your help.

ps: sorry for my english!!

Comment: Seems to be working just fine here. Are you sure you're not changing some value somewhere else?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. auxCount and userCount are used only in this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try this for loops as i have used in my app it worked for me.

to find out the number of rows depending on number of columns and total count

```
int r;
float rem = [dao libraryCount] % kCol;
if(rem == 0.0f)
    r = floor([dao libraryCount]/kD);
else
    r = ceil([dao libraryCount]/kD);
```

here `r` is for number if row `[dao libraryCount` is total number of items and `kCol` is fix number of column for you it is 3  and `kD` is same as `kCol` only deference is it is type of float ie 3.0 in your case

then use the for loop as below

```
for (int row = 0; row < r; ++row)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < kCol; ++col)
    {
       //Your Code to display or any thing
    }
}
```

for `auxCount` use this code

```
int index = (row * kCol) + col;
        if(index < [dao libraryCount])
        {
            //Your Code to display or any thing
        }
```

put this in side both `for` loop instead of using `++`
just change the both `for` loops and replace `if` condition with appropriate variables

Enjoy Coding :)
And Good Luck

**any help is needed just comment me i will love to help you**

Comment: I'm not sure I understood but I'll try to implement it